# How to trace a specific historic file in the Linux kernel tree: Git question

Tags: linux, drivers, git, source, trace

I'm currently manually building a Linux image with some specific drivers for a Xilinx Zynqmp device. Aside from the main Linux tree, there are 2 other  mirrored Linux repositories, one from Xilinx and another where the driver was developed with.

I noticed some differences within the source files. I know about the "git blame" function and it tells me it is an older Xilinx developed file which was being used for the driver development.

My Question:
How do I track down the exact source file where the driver was build on? I would like to know which branch or tag was cloned/merged in order to build the driver. Because logically the driver developers kernel leaps behind the Xilinx dev kernel. How do I do this?

Any other git tips & tricks in this matter are very much welcome.

Comment: I am not sure to understand exactly your need, maybe you should add details on the specific git repository you are looking at, the files you are interested in, and what commands you tried already. As for tips and tricks, the following commands besides `git blame` can be useful to do searches: `git log -S`, `git log -G` and `git bisect`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  I know the question is a bit vague. I have this driver from Analog Devices and they claim the Xilinx linux repo get's merged periodically with theirs. But it is very unclear to me which branch or tag was used as a base for their driver. I am looking for some tricks or tools to navigate through the giant Linux repository and track down what items the driver authors changed or not.

Comment: I am not even understanding if you have git IDs or not. If so, it should be easy which commit was a fork  or a merge from which one(s). If not, see my comment above for other comments to do kind of text search inside git history.

Comment: @PatrickMevzekI managed to get an overview from the history using following command: git rev-hist 123456..HEAD  The correct ID came from the tag out of the other repository. I'll try your command later on.  Thanks for you help.